# React Tooltip doesn't show on hover

Tags: reactjs, react-tooltip

Component -

```
<InfoCard
     count={passengersCount}
     text={`${t('dailyPassengers')}`}
     data-for="dailyPassengers"
     data-tip
/>
```

Tooltip Code -

```
    <ReactTooltip
          id="dailyPassengers"
          place="right"
          type="light"
          borderColor="gray"
          border
    >
           <p>hi</p>
      </ReactTooltip>
```

Any idea why doesnt it appear on hover?
Thanks.

Comment: Please create a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) on codesandbox

Comment: Solved it, but thanks anyway :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it,
the data-for and data-top attributes must be on a div, not a react component,
like so:

```
const InfoCard = ({
   count,
   text,
   margin,
   tooltipId,
}: Props): JSX.Element => {
   return (
      <Card margin={margin}>
         <div data-for={tooltipId} data-tip>
            <CountText>{count}</CountText>
            <Text>{text}</Text>
         </div>
      </Card>
   );
};
```